# How to get a location or simply an id to provide location based content?

Tags: android, api, google-maps, geolocation, beacon

I'm building an android app and I want my app to provide location based content. For example if I'm near a museum or in one, shows me details about that museum. The thing is how to identify that place.What is the best method?

Well beacons do the job perfectly, where they emit a signal that has an id, my app reads the id and provide related information.But it would take some time for me to get some beacons so if there are any similar technologies, please list them down here.

An GPS technology or APIs are fine as long as its simple without being overly complicated since I just want my app to verify it has arrived to a location, and based on that, just show the content.

what are the options I have got?

Comment: you can use geolocation API to know where the user is.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option might be to use your phone gps location, without beacons.

For this you need to find a museum api to display information about nearest museums.

Then, you can use `LocationManager` in Android to first check if location permissions are granted:

```
private Location  getLastKnownLocation() {
    Location n = null;
    LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    List<String> locationProviders = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);

    for (String provider : locationProviders) {
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    n = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
   }
  }
    return n;
}
```

Then we need to do the following:

```
Location gps = getLastKnownLocation();

String latitude = Double.toString(gps.getLatitude());
Log.e(“User Location Latitude”, “” + gps.getLatitude());

String longitude = Double.toString(gps.getLongitude());
Log.e(“User Location Longitude”, “” + gps.getLongitude());

Uri baseUri = Uri.parse(“YOUR_API_URL” + latitude + “YOUR_API_URL” + longitude + “YOUR_API_URL”);
Log.e(“Api Query”, “” + baseUri);

Uri.Builder uriBuilder = baseUri.buildUpon();
```

Another elegant way to get a location would be to implement `getLastKnownLocation` the Reactive way.

This approach allows keeping code concise using lambdas, chaining observables & using deferred computation. A way to do so would be to combine both the [RxPermissions](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions) library & [RxLocation](https://github.com/patloew/RxLocation) library for flexibility.

Below code for this post is taken from both libraries’ official documentations provided, with some modifications to suit this discussion:

```
final RxPermissions rxPermissions = new RxPermissions(this);

rxLocation = new RxLocation(this);
```

Like in the conventional non-reactive method earlier, we create `getLastKnownLocation`:

```
private void getLastKnownLocation(final String apiSearch) {
    compositeDisposable.add(rxPermissions
        .request(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        .subscribe(granted -> {
           if (granted) {
```

The `lastLocation()` below belongs to a `Maybe<T>`, which is a lazy implementation that represents a deferred Rx computation.

It allows `onSuccess`, `onComplete` & `onError` to operate as mutually exclusive events, unlike an Observable, such that if location is not available, no value is returned to the subscriber.

Using this library wraps the LocationServices.FusedLocationApi in `rxLocation.location()`:

```
      rxLocation.location().lastLocation()

         .doOnSuccess(location -> {
// Your code implementation for Received Last Known Location: If last known location is already known & exists, to pass the existing last known location into your museum api, to fetch results to your adapter   
})

        .doOnComplete(() -> {
// Your code implementation for handling the Location Request, then doing a Completing action: This sends a new request to request the latest user location, before subscribing to your museum api, to fetch results to your adapter   

})
        .doOnError(throwable ->
// Your code implementation to handle any errors thrown: Pops a toast message to prompt user to enable GPS location on phone   

})
```

Following the documentation, we send a request for user’s location:

```
private void latestLocation(final String apiSearch) {
  LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
      .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
      .setInterval(6000); // 6s
```

We subscribe to location updates, to prevent location returning null, which is possible in conventional non-reactive method. Using this library wraps the LocationServices.FusedLocationApi in `rxLocation.location()`:

```
rxLocationSubscriber = rxLocation.location().updates(locationRequest)
```

Because `fromLocation()` call below belongs to a `Maybe<T>`, it returns a Maybe. We convert it into an Observable through `toObservable`, to use it with `flatMap`, that supports thread concurrency. This library wraps Geocoder API in `rxLocation.geocoding()`:

```
.flatMap(location ->

    rxLocation.geocoding().fromLocation(location).toObservable())

.subscribe(location -> {

    // your code implementation for museum api

    rxLocationSubscriber.dispose();
  });
}
```

I think the most straightforward approach would be the first method outlined.

Hope this is helpful.